# Get the generic arguments of a PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect applied to Generic Method

Tags: c#, postsharp

Given an PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect of the following set-up, how do I get `typeof(T1)` during `OnEntry` or `OnExit`:

*Bonus Points for no reflection used.*

**Aspect:**

```
public class MyOnMethodBoundaryAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {   
        //args.??? -- How to get typeof(T1)
    }
}
```

**Method:**

```
[MyOnMethodBoundaryAspect]
public void Foo<T1>()
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used PostSharp for ages, but it *looks* like you just need to use the [`Method`](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/P_PostSharp_Aspects_MethodExecutionArgs_Method.htm) property:

> If the executed method is generic or if its declaring type is generic, the current property contains the generic instance being executed.

So you should be able to use [`MethodBase.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getgenericarguments.aspx) to get at the type arguments.

Comment: This is correct. `args.Method` will contain the correct generic instance of the calling method.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just changed over to a Pro licence, Method was null and wasn't populated 'cause I hadn't referenced it in my code yet.  Like here, that I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559589/postsharp-newbie-why-is-args-instance-null